# Need step by step tutorial to get cites using TeXnicCenter

Tags: bibliographies, texniccenter

I have a document, I can't seem to figure out how to compile so that the document 'sees' the bibliography (`.bib` file) in TeXnicCenter.

Here are my bibliography commands:

```
\bibstyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{BibTest}
```

I compile using the LaTeX-DVI-PDF profile, in which I have *not* selected the "*Do Not Use Bibtex in this profile*":

[image]

The document compiles just fine, except for the cites, for which I get question marks.

Do I need to use a package in order to get the bibliography to compile or what do I need to do?

Comment: You should show a visual of your output profile LaTeX-DVI-PDF. Also, did you compile multiple times (see [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764))?

Comment: Do you use TeXnicCenter "Projects"? If so, is "Uses BibTeX" checked in the Project Properties? DID YOU COMPILE TWICE?

Comment: I use "Files", not "Projects".  I compiled twice (well, more than twice..).

Comment: If you are not using a "Project", then you have to manually select Build -> Current File -> BibTeX in order to run BibTeX. Then recompile the document after doing that.

Comment: Here is a link to a pic of the output profile:  http://imgur.com/jSGsUp0     Thanks!!

Comment: "If you are not using a "Project", then you have to manually select Build -> Current File -> BibTeX in order to run BibTeX. Then recompile the document after doing that."   Ooh, that is promising!  Doing that, I now get an Bibtex error message "I found no \bibstyle command while reading thesis.aux", although I have the bibstyle command as in my original post

Comment: `\bibstyle` should not appear in your `.tex` file; there it should be some `\bibliographystyle`. `\bibstyle` is written into the generated `.aux` file by the `\bibliographystyle` instruction.

Comment: And I also just realized: I was wrong about needing to manually run `bibtex`. It does work when choosing "Build current file" (Ctrl + F7). At least it helped you to see the log messages. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom!  I changed to include the \bibliographystyle command, compiled the document twice, and then Build-Current File-Bibtex  and I HAVE ACTUAL CITES IN MY DOCUMENT!!  THANK YOU!!

Comment: @PaulGessler - You should write up a combination of your comments as a stand-alone answer.

Answer (score 2):

`\bibstyle` does not belong in the `.tex` file: this macro is meant to be used in the `.aux` file, and it is written there by `\bibliographystyle`, which *should* be used in the `.tex` file.

So `bibtex` complains that it "found no `\bibstyle` command while reading `thesis.aux`".

Use `\bibliographystyle` in the `.tex` file, then the correct macros will be written to the `.aux` file, and all will be well.

As an aside: if you're writing something as big as a thesis (deduced from the filename in the error message since no MWE was given), I highly recommend you create a TeXnicCenter project for this. It makes dealing with multiple included files much easier.